# Rspec: the proper way to use params in a get method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

This is my RSpec test:

```
describe "GET #show" do
  it "assigns the requested user to @user" do
    user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
   get :show, id: user
    assigns(:user).should eq(user)
  end
end
```

This is my rails controller:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end
```

I get the following error message:

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController GET #show assigns the requested user to @user
     Failure/Error: get :show, id: user
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find User without an ID
     # /home/tim/fairym/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:25:in `show'
     # ./users_controller_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What is the proper way to use the get method here in order to make the test pass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `FactoryGirl.create` and not `build`. The reason is that `create` actually makes an entry in the database, including ID. `build` only makes an object in the memory, without an ID.